# Excel find proper value to put formula within range

Tags: excel

Sorry for the poor title, I didn't know how better to phrase this.

Here's my question, I have a spreadsheet which I use for quoting jobs.
I manually adjust the markup on the materials until the total profit/total retail = Margin.
Is there a way to automatically adjust the markup to achieve a desired Margin? Currently I have to just type in a number, see how it turns out, then increase or lower the number until the margin is where I want it.

Here's a synopsis of the formulas I currently use...

```
Margin = Total Profit / Total Retail
Total Profit = Total Retail - Total Cost
Total Retail = Labor + Marked up Equipment
Marked up Equipment = (Tax and Shipping(10%) + Markup %) * Equipment Cost + Equipment cost
```

So what I'm looking for is for excel to automatically calculate the Markup% for a desired margin.

Is this possible?

Additional info. The spreadsheet was written with Excel 2003, however we will be updating to 2013 within a year. So ideally the solution would work in 2003, and 2013, but ultimately it only must work in 2013.

Comment: You can do [what-if analysis](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/introduction-to-what-if-analysis-HA010243164.aspx) in Excel. Use Solver, Goal Seek, others.

Answer (score 2):

If this is just a spreadsheet for calculation, and not something you pass on to your customer, the Excel Solver Add-In (included with Excel but not activated by default) will do what you want.